# Вопрос с preg_match_all (парсинг)

Tags: php

**Здравствуйте.**

Имелась ссылка/анкор следующего вида:

```
https://site.com/pyk/?git_id=0&dir=1&p=1
```

**Контент парсил следующим образом:**

```
preg_match_all('#href="https://site.com/pyk/\?git_id=0.*dir=([0-9]+)(;|&).*p=1" class="main_item.*>(.*)</a>#siU', $file, $dir);
```

Там были категории. Всё прекрасно работало.

Но сейчас ссылка стала так:

[https://site.com/pyk/Название_Папки](https://site.com/pyk/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8)

или

[https://site.com/pyk/Название_Папки/Название_Папки2](https://site.com/pyk/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B82) и т.п. **(СТАЛО КИРИЛЛИЦА)**

Как же теперь направить вышеуказанный код на правильный путь?

Пробовал все, не получается. По желанию могу остальной код массива скинуть.

**ps: За помощь в виде благодарности 100р на кошелек на печеньки)**

Comment: с такими url наоборот ведь проще парсить, даже регулярки не нужны - explode по слешу.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю Вас. Можно пример?

Comment: посмотрите [пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c6f9339a740219a388eb1c4b8acb33bc5e6b20d5)